# jquery UI Accordion mouseover effect

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

I am using the 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#hoverintent (mouseover effect) 
how can the accordion close automatically on mouseout.

http://premiumfitnessuae.com/services.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this on mouseout

to close all (only possible with collapsible:true)
in .accordion( "activate" , index )

Comment: thanks, I used 'collapsible:true', its working when you hover mouse on the heading, its not working on mouse out.

Answer (score 0):

http://demos.w3avenue.com/cross-browser-pure-css3-vertical-accordion/

see this it might be helpful  pure css3 accordion